# Программа работает несколько часов нормально и падает

Tags: python, исключения

Есть программа, которая отправляет данные на сервер, считывает данные с него, считывает показания датчиков и отправляет команды исполнительным механизмам. В программе есть циклы-демоны, которые запускаются из main-файла(с GUI). Программа работает нормально насколько часов, но потом зависает или аварийно завершается. Что только не делал - ничего не помогло избавиться от этой проблемы. В частности я не понимаю почему в последнем листинге вылетели ошибки при погружении функции в сон и последующего ее запуска? Есть подозрение что где-то нужно поставить Except, но какие именно и где пока не вкурю, т.к. уже из головы пар валит. Если кому несложно, предложите пути решения и главное объясните, почему так происходит. P.s. Программа написана лично мной для личных целей(мини умный дом). Это не курсовая, дипломная или какая-то другая работа, да и я давно не студент. Изучаю питон для личного развития и хочу понять что я делаю не так. Код и листинг из PyCharm прилагаю.

Файл Stream_2.py

```
import gc
import threading
from time import sleep
import requests
import Variables

lock = threading.RLock()
def start1():
    a=1
    while a==1:
        lock.acquire()
        try:
            r4_0 = Variables.parsing_GPIO_4relay1
            r4_1 = str(r4_0[0])
            r4_2 = str(r4_0[1])
            r4_3 = str(r4_0[2])
            r4_4 = str(r4_0[3])
            params = {'params': str(Variables.parsing_ESP1),
                      'params1': str(Variables.Sadok_Light1),
                      'params2_1': r4_1,
                      'params2_2': r4_2,
                      'params2_3': r4_3,
                      'params2_4': r4_4, 'control': 'home'}

            r = requests.get('http://f0555107.xsph.ru/index.php', params=params)
            r.encoding = "UTF8"
            print('start1 = Ok')
            print(r.text)
            # params.clear()
            r.close()
            break
        except:
            params = {'params': '0', 'params1': '0', 'params2_1': '0', 'params2_2': '0', 'params2_3': '0', 'params2_4': '0', 'control': 'home'}
            r = requests.get('http://f0555107.xsph.ru/index.php', params=params)
            r.encoding = "UTF8"
            print('except start1' + r.text)
            params.clear()
            r.close()
            sleep(5.0)
            pass
        finally:
          lock.release()
    gc.collect()
    sleep(60.0)
    start1()


def start2():
    a = 1
    while a == 1:
          global lines
          lock.acquire()
          try:
            url = "http://f0555107.xsph.ru/hello.html"
            r = requests.get(url)
            r.encoding = "UTF8"
            print('start2 = Ok')
            with open('response_server.html', 'w') as output_file:
              output_file.write(r.text)
            output_file.close()
            with open('response_server.txt', 'w') as output_file:
              output_file.write(r.text)
            output_file.close()

            text_file = open("response_server.html", "r")
            lines = text_file.read().split(',')
            print(lines)
            # print(len(lines))
            text_file.close()
            Variables.receive_from_server = lines
            Variables.receive_from_server1 = lines[0]
            Variables.receive_from_server1 = lines[1]
            Variables.receive_from_server1 = lines[2]
            Variables.receive_from_server1 = lines[3]
            Variables.receive_from_server1 = lines[4]
            Variables.receive_from_server1 = lines[5]
            Variables.receive_from_server1 = lines[6]
            r.close()
            break

          except:
            lines.append('0')
            print('Except! start2')
            sleep(5.0)
            pass
          finally:
              lock.release()
    gc.collect()
    sleep(70.0)
    start2()



def parsing_ESP():
  global str3
  a = 1
  while a == 1:
          lock.acquire()
          try:
            url = "http://192.168.0.110/sensors/adci1/"
            r = requests.get(url)
            r.encoding = "UTF8"
            with open('test.html', 'w') as output_file:
              output_file.write(r.text)
            output_file.close()
            with open('test1.txt', 'w') as output_file:
              output_file.write(r.text)
            output_file.close()
            f = open('test1.txt')
            str1=f.read()
            f.close()

            str2=str1[str1.find(";") + 1 : ]
            str3=str2[str2.find(":") + 1 : str2.find(";")]
            Variables.parsing_ESP = int(str3)
            Variables.parsing_ESP1 = int(str3)
            print('parsing_ESP = Ok')
            r.close()
            break
          except:
            print(' Except! parsing_ESP')
            url= 'http://192.168.0.110/configrst?st=1'
            r = requests.get(url)
            str3=110
            Variables.parsing_ESP = int(str3)
            Variables.parsing_ESP1 = int(str3)
            sleep(5.0)
            r.close()
            pass
          finally:
              lock.release()
  gc.collect()
  sleep(60.0)
  parsing_ESP()


def parsing_GPIO_Sadok():
   a = 1
   while a == 1:
          lock.acquire()
          try:
            url = "http://192.168.0.100/gpioprint"
            r = requests.get(url)
            Variables.status_code_sadok = r.status_code
            r.encoding = "UTF8"

            with open('sadok.html', 'w') as output_file:
              output_file.write(r.text)
            output_file.close()
            with open('sadok1.txt', 'w') as output_file:
              output_file.write(r.text)
            output_file.close()
            f = open('sadok1.txt')
            str_sad = f.read()
            # print(str_sad)
            f.close()
            str_sad2 = str_sad[:str_sad.find(";") + 1]
            str_sad3 = str_sad2[str_sad2.find(":") + 1: str_sad2.find(";")]
            Variables.Sadok_Light=str_sad3
            Variables.Sadok_Light1 = str_sad3
            print('parsing_GPIO_Sadok = Ok ')
            r.close()
            break
          except:
            print(' Except! parsing_GPIO_Sadok')
            str_sad3=1
            Variables.Sadok_Light = str_sad3
            Variables.Sadok_Light1 = str_sad3
            sleep(5.0)
            pass
          finally:
              lock.release()
   gc.collect()
   sleep(30.0)
   parsing_GPIO_Sadok()


def parsing_GPIO_4relay11():
  a = 1
  while a == 1:
          lock.acquire()
          try:
            url = "http://192.168.0.120/gpioprint"
            r = requests.get(url)
            Variables.status_code_4relay = r.status_code
            r.encoding = "UTF8"

            with open('4relay.txt', 'w') as output_file:
             output_file.write(r.text)
            output_file.close()
            f = open('4relay.txt')
            str_4relay = f.read()
            f.close()
            print('parsing_GPIO_4relay = Ok')
            str_4relay2 = str_4relay[str_4relay.find(":") + 1:]

            r1 = str_4relay2[: str_4relay2.find(";")]
            r2 = str_4relay[10:11]
            r3 = str_4relay[18:19]
            r4 = str_4relay[23:24]
            relay_list = [r1, r2, r3, r4]
            Variables.parsing_GPIO_4relay = relay_list
            Variables.parsing_GPIO_4relay1 = relay_list
            print('Variables.parsing_GPIO_4relay =' + str(Variables.parsing_GPIO_4relay))
            r.close()
            break
          except:
              r1 = '0'
              r2 = '0'
              r3 = '0'
              r4 = '0'
              relay_list = [r1, r2, r3, r4]
              Variables.parsing_GPIO_4relay = relay_list
              relay_list.clear()
              print('Except! parsing_GPIO_4relay11')
              sleep(5.0)
              pass
          finally:
              lock.release()
  gc.collect()
  sleep(30.0)
  parsing_GPIO_4relay11()
```

Файл logic_center.py

```
import gc
import threading
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
import requests
import Variables

lock = threading.RLock()
def logicks_Sadok_Light():
    a = 1
    while a == 1:
           lock.acquire()
           try:
               if int(Variables.parsing_ESP) <=100:
                  url= Variables.GPIO_sad_on
                  requests.get(url)
                  print('Night street')
               else:
                   url = Variables.GPIO_sad_off
                   requests.get(url)
                   print('Day street!')
               break
           except:
               print('Except! logics sadok light')
               sleep(5.0)
               pass
           finally:
               lock.release()
    gc.collect()

def logicks_4relay_Light():
    a = 1
    while a == 1:
        lock.acquire()
        try:
            if int(Variables.parsing_ESP) <= 100:
                url = Variables.GPIO_4relay1_on
                requests.get(url)
                url = Variables.GPIO_4relay2_on
                requests.get(url)
                url = Variables.GPIO_4relay3_on
                requests.get(url)
                url = Variables.GPIO_4relay4_on
                requests.get(url)
                print('4Relay Night')
            else:
                url = Variables.GPIO_4relay1_off
                requests.get(url)
                url = Variables.GPIO_4relay2_off
                requests.get(url)
                url = Variables.GPIO_4relay3_off
                requests.get(url)
                url = Variables.GPIO_4relay4_off
                requests.get(url)
                print('4 Relay Day!')
            break
        except:
            print('Except logics 4 relay!')
            sleep(5.0)
            pass
        finally:
            lock.release()
    gc.collect()

def change_position_relay():
    print(' написать change_position_relay()')

def remote_control_install():
    a = 1
    while a == 1:
        lock.acquire()
        try:
            logicks_Sadok_Light()
            logicks_4relay_Light()
            break
        except:
            print('except! remote_control_install!')
            sleep(5.0)
            pass
        finally:
           lock.release()
    gc.collect()
    sleep(20.0)
    remote_control_install()
```

Листинг в PyCharm

```
Получены новые вводные: данные датчика ESP - 14, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, home
parsing_ESP = Ok
parsing_GPIO_Sadok = Ok 
parsing_GPIO_4relay = Ok
Variables.parsing_GPIO_4relay =['1', '1', '1', '1']
Night street
4Relay Night
parsing_GPIO_Sadok = Ok 
parsing_GPIO_4relay = Ok
Variables.parsing_GPIO_4relay =['1', '1', '1', '1']
start2 = Ok
['14', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'home']
Night street
4Relay Night
Night street
4Relay Night
start1 = Ok
 Получены новые вводные: данные датчика ESP - 13, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, home
parsing_ESP = Ok
parsing_GPIO_Sadok = Ok 
parsing_GPIO_4relay = Ok
Variables.parsing_GPIO_4relay =['1', '1', '1', '1']
Night street
4Relay Night
parsing_GPIO_Sadok = Ok 
parsing_GPIO_4relay = Ok
Variables.parsing_GPIO_4relay =['1', '1', '1', '1']
check server 200
status_code Light_sensor_connection: 200
Night street
4Relay Night
start2 = Ok
['', '', '', '', '', '', '']
Night street
4Relay Night
start1 = Ok
 Получены новые вводные: данные датчика ESP - 14, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, home
parsing_ESP = Ok
parsing_GPIO_Sadok = Ok 
parsing_GPIO_4relay = Ok
Variables.parsing_GPIO_4relay =['1', '1', '1', '1']
Night street
4Relay Night
parsing_GPIO_Sadok = Ok 
parsing_GPIO_4relay = Ok
Variables.parsing_GPIO_4relay =['1', '1', '1', '1']
google.com 200
Night street
4Relay Night
start2 = Ok
['', '', '', '', '', '', '']
start1 = Ok
 Получены новые вводные: данные датчика ESP - 13, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, home
Night street
4Relay Night
 Except! parsing_ESP
Exception in thread Thread-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 96, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 86, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
parsing_GPIO_Sadok = Ok 
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 394, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 234, in request
    super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 1255, in request
parsing_GPIO_4relay = Ok
Variables.parsing_GPIO_4relay =['1', '1', '1', '1']
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 1301, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 1250, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 1010, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 950, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 200, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 181, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000000000A54B2E0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 574, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='192.168.0.110', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /sensors/adci1/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000000000A54B2E0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Java work\eclipse\test\package1_copy\Stream_2.py", line 86, in parsing_ESP
    r = requests.get(url)
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='192.168.0.110', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /sensors/adci1/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000000000A54B2E0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\Java work\eclipse\test\package1_copy\Stream_2.py", line 114, in parsing_ESP
    parsing_ESP()
  File "D:\Java work\eclipse\test\package1_copy\Stream_2.py", line 114, in parsing_ESP
    parsing_ESP()
  File "D:\Java work\eclipse\test\package1_copy\Stream_2.py", line 114, in parsing_ESP
    parsing_ESP()
  [Previous line repeated 326 more times]
  File "D:\Java work\eclipse\test\package1_copy\Stream_2.py", line 106, in parsing_ESP
    r.request.get(url)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'r' referenced before assignment
Night street
4Relay Night
Night street
4Relay Night
parsing_GPIO_Sadok = Ok 
parsing_GPIO_4relay = Ok
Variables.parsing_GPIO_4relay =['1', '1', '1', '1']
Night street
4Relay Night
start1 = Ok
 Получены новые вводные: данные датчика ESP - 13, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, home
start2 = Ok
['13', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'home']
parsing_GPIO_Sadok = Ok 
parsing_GPIO_4relay = Ok
Variables.parsing_GPIO_4relay =['1', '1', '1', '1']
Night street
4Relay Night
Получены новые вводные: данные датчика ESP - 13, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, home
parsing_GPIO_Sadok = Ok 
parsing_GPIO_4relay = Ok
Variables.parsing_GPIO_4relay =['1', '1', '1', '1']
Night street
4Relay Night
start2 = Ok
['13', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'home']
parsing_GPIO_Sadok = Ok 
parsing_GPIO_4relay = Ok
Variables.parsing_GPIO_4relay =['1', '1', '1', '1']
Night street
4Relay Night
Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.
Python runtime state: initialized

Thread 0x00001268 (most recent call first):
  File "D:\Java work\eclipse\test\package1_copy\Stream_2.py", line 188 in parsing_GPIO_4relay11
  File "D:\Java work\eclipse\test\package1_copy\Stream_2.py", line 189 in parsing_GPIO_4relay11
  File "D:\Java work\eclipse\test\package1_copy\Stream_2.py", line 189 in parsing_GPIO_4relay11
  File "D:\Java work\eclipse\test\package1_copy\Stream_2.py", line 189 in parsing_GPIO_4relay11
  ...

Thread 0x00001474 (most recent call first):
  File "D:\Java work\eclipse\test\package1_copy\Stream_2.py", line 148 in parsing_GPIO_Sadok
  File "D:\Java work\eclipse\test\package1_copy\Stream_2.py", line 149 in parsing_GPIO_Sadok
  File "D:\Java work\eclipse\test\package1_copy\Stream_2.py", line 149 in parsing_GPIO_Sadok
  File "D:\Java work\eclipse\test\package1_copy\Stream_2.py", line 149 in parsing_GPIO_Sadok
  File "D:\Java work\eclipse\test\package1_copy\Stream_2.py", line 149 in parsing_GPIO_Sadok
  File "D:\Java work\eclipse\test\package1_copy\Stream_2.py", line 149 in parsing_GPIO_Sadok
  File "D:\Java work\eclipse\test\package1_copy\Stream_2.py", line 149 in parsing_GPIO_Sadok
  ...

Thread 0x00001374 (most recent call first):
  File "D:\Java work\eclipse\test\package1_copy\Stream_2.py", line 39 in start1
  File "D:\Java work\eclipse\test\package1_copy\Stream_2.py", line 40 in start1
  File "D:\Java work\eclipse\test\package1_copy\Stream_2.py", line 40 in start1
  File "D:\Java work\eclipse\test\package1_copy\Stream_2.py", line 40 in start1
  ...

Thread 0x00000ba0 (most recent call first):
  File "D:\Java work\eclipse\test\package1_copy\Stream_2.py", line 77 in start2
  File "D:\Java work\eclipse\test\package1_copy\Stream_2.py", line 78 in start2
  File "D:\Java work\eclipse\test\package1_copy\Stream_2.py", line 78 in start2
  File "D:\Java work\eclipse\test\package1_copy\Stream_2.py", line 78 in start2
  File "D:\Java work\eclipse\test\package1_copy\Stream_2.py", line 78 in start2
  ...

Current thread 0x00000ca4 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\email\utils.py", line 57 in _has_surrogates
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\email\_policybase.py", line 287 in _sanitize_header
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\email\_policybase.py", line 316 in header_fetch_parse
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\email\message.py", line 471 in get
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\email\message.py", line 578 in get_content_type
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\email\message.py", line 594 in get_content_maintype
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 295 in _parsegen
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 180 in _call_parse
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 176 in feed
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\email\parser.py", line 56 in parse
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\email\parser.py", line 67 in parsestr
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 225 in parse_headers
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 331 in begin
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 1347 in getresponse
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 440 in _make_request
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 699 in urlopen
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439 in send
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655 in send
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542 in request
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61 in request
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76 in get
  File "D:\Java work\eclipse\test\package1_copy\logic_center.py", line 13 in logicks_Sadok_Light
  File "D:\Java work\eclipse\test\package1_copy\logic_center.py", line 61 in remote_control_install
  File "D:\Java work\eclipse\test\package1_copy\logic_center.py", line 70 in remote_control_install
  
  ...

Thread 0x000010f8 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\Noutbook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1429 in mainloop
  File "D:/Java work/eclipse/test/package1_copy/Lesson_3.py", line 437 in <module>
```

Comment: По поводу вылета, ты оперативку проверял? У тебя там ее не переполняет (я как то давно лажанулся, забыл обнулять одну штуку и она, эм... забила мне где то 10+ гб памяти)? Не обязательно, что у тебя так же, но вдруг? Проверить не помешает.

Comment: Примерно `r.request.get(url)` получает исключение будучи в блоке except. То есть у вас получается исключение в обработке исключения. Попробуйте может загнать код в цикл и выбивать из него если все ок иначе повторять.  А ошибка походу из за неудачного обращения по сети. + обратите внимание на область видимости `r` которую вы используете до объявления

Comment: Нельзя ли поподробнее про "Загнать код в цикл и выбивать из него, если все Ок, иначе повторять".  Т.е. например в while загнать содержимое отдельно try и отдельно except и например по r.status_code==200 выкидывать из цикла?

Comment: По сути `try` блок у вас завершится командой `break` (прерывание) а блок except будет выводить сообщение об ошибке и заканчиваться `continue` (повторение)

Comment: Теперь ясно, буду пробовать сделать так. Благодарю.

Comment: Загнал все в циклы, как советовали - программа падать перестала, но теперь вылезла новая проблема - программа потихоньку кушает оперативную память. Позакрывал все что можно, в каждой функции принудительно запускаю GC - все равно понемногу ест. Какие есть варианты возврата памяти системе или я что-то не закрыл или не сбросил?

Comment: Код в файлах обновил.

Comment: Сейчас `start1` и `start2` вызывают сами себя, через какое-то время стек заканчивается и программа падает с переполнением стека, плюс отжирает по ходу память.

Comment: Отжирает стопудово! Посоветуйте действенное решение. пожалуйста.  Может убрать вызов из себя и оставить просто нужную sleep() в бесконечном цикле внутри функции?

Comment: Зачем вы вызываете функции рекурсивно? Что вы хотите этим добиться? `Previous line repeated 326 more times` - у вас программа не смогла достучаться по сети в `parsing_ESP`, получили исключение, и пошли в рекурсивный вызов. Чтоб помочь нужно понять зачем вы это делаете? Чего пытаетесь достичь?

Comment: Это похоже на попытку реализовать вечный цикл с опросом датчиков. И (неудачная) попытка обрабатывать ошибки и проблемы с тем, что при ошибке цикл заканчивается. Так?

Comment: @Roman Konoval Да, да! Это я лоханулся с рекурсивными вызовами в силу еще малых знаний Python. Просто учу сам, подсказать некому. Рекурсивные вызовы убрал, заменил на вечный while со sleep() внутри. Но осталась проблема в файле logic_cetnter. Я обернул remote_control_install(), но какая-то функция все равно понемногу жрет память. Пока найти не могу.